# Android : Use Camera to display image to ImageView and Save to Gallery

Tags: android, camera, gallery, android-imageview

I am making an app which has an option to get an image from the camera or from the gallery and display it in an ImageView.
I got this from the [Android Developers Tutorial.](http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html)
I am using a DialogInterface for this one:

```
private void selectImage() {
        final CharSequence[] items = { "Take Photo", "Choose from Library",
                "Cancel" };

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ReportIncident.this);
        builder.setTitle("Add Picture");
        builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                if (items[item].equals("Take Photo")) {
                    takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent

                    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                        // Create the File where the photo should go

                        try {
                            photoFile = createImageFile();
                            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));

                            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, 0);


                        } catch (IOException ex) {
                            // Error occurred while creating the File
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                } else if (items[item].equals("Choose from Library")) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(
                            Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                    intent.setType("image/*");
                    startActivityForResult(
                            Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select File"), 1);
                } else if (items[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }
```

createImageFile creates the directory/File where the photo will be saved:

```
private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "FIREFLOOD_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    mCurrentPhotoPath = "file:" + image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}
```

The 'Choose from Library' part is already working but I have a problem with 'Take Photo' part. Specifically on this line:

```
takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
galleryAddPic();
startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, 0);
```

> Having the putExtra() and galleryAddPic() before the startActivityOnResult() 
>   crashes the app after taking the picture but successfully saves the image to
>   gallery. But deleting these two methods from the code displays the photo taken 
>   to the ImageView reportImage.

startActivityForResult displays the image taken to the ImageView through activityOnResult:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == 1) {

                onSelectFromGalleryResult(data);
            }else if (requestCode == 0) {
                Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
                reportImage.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);




            }
        }
    }
```

Saving the image to gallery is performed by galleryAddPic:

```
private void galleryAddPic() {

        Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
        File f = new File(mCurrentPhotoPath);
        Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
        mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
        this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
    }
```

> The question is where can I put these two methods (putExtra and
>   galleryAddPic) to make these two funtions work:
>
> 1. display the photo taken to ImageView
> 2. save the photo to gallery at the same time.
>
> I can't make these two work altogether. Please help. I tried to put
>   the putExtra and galleryAddPic on the onAcitivityResult but it still
>   crashes. galleryAddPic won't work without the putExtra.

Comment: I have to work this on Android 4.4.2 Kitkat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This tutorial will help you try this link 
http://www.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-working-with-camera-api/

Comment: its working for me iam also using the same code withit the same device kitkat 4.4.4 its working fine for me

Comment: Gee Thanks!! I found that you'll got a NullPointerException everytime startResultforActivity is called. I override two methods : onSavedInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState to restore the fileuri and use it to diplay the image to the imageview..